# Akka - load balancing and full use of the processor

Tags: load-balancing, akka

I wrote a matrix multiplication algorithm, which uses parallel collections, to speed up the multiplication.

It goes like that:

```
(0 until M1_ROWS).grouped(PARTITION_ROWS).toList.par.map( i => 
  singleThreadedMultiplicationFAST(i.toArray.map(m1(_)), m2) 
).reduce(_++_)
```

Now I would like to do the same in Akka, so what I did is:

```
val multiplyer = actorOf[Pool] 
multiplyer start 
val futures = (0 until M1_ROWS).grouped(PARTITION_ROWS).map( i => 
  multiplyer ? MultiplyMatrix(i.toArray.map(m1(_)), m2) 
) 
futures.map(_.get match { case res :Array[Array[Double]] => res }).reduce(_++_) 

class Multiplyer extends akka.actor.Actor{ 
  protected def receive = { 
    case MultiplyMatrix(m1, m2) => self reply singleThreadedMultiplicationFAST (m1,m2) 
  } 
} 
class Pool extends Actor with DefaultActorPool 
  with FixedCapacityStrategy with RoundRobinSelector { 

  def receive = _route 
  def partialFill = false 
  def selectionCount = 1 
  def instance = actorOf[Multiplyer] 
  def limit = 32 // I tried 256 with no effect either 
}
```

It turned out that actor based version of this algorithm is using only 
200% on my i7 sandybridge, while the parallel collections version is 
using 600% of processor and is 4-5x faster. 
I thought it might be the dispatcher and tried this:

```
self.dispatcher = Dispatchers.newThreadBasedDispatcher(self, mailboxCapacity = 100)
```

and this(I shared this one between actors):

```
val messageDispatcher = Dispatchers.newExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher("d1")
  .withNewBoundedThrea dPoolWithLinkedBlockingQueueWithUnboundedCapacity(100)
  .setCorePoolSize(16)
  .setMaxPoolSize(128)
  .setKeepAliveTimeInMillis(60000).build
```

But I didn't observe any changes. Still 200% processor usage only and 
the algorithm is 4-5 times slower than the parallel collections 
version.

I am sure I am doing something silly so please help!!!:)

Answer (score 2):

This expression:

```
val futures = (0 until M1_ROWS).grouped(PARTITION_ROWS).map( i => 
  multiplyer ? MultiplyMatrix(i.toArray.map(m1(_)), m2) 
)
```

creates a lazy collection, so your _.get makes your entire program serial.
So the solution is to make that expression strict by adding toList or similar.